# What percentage of damage to heroes is permanent?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

In Battlefront 2 the hero units unlike most other units take permanent damage as well as temporary damage when hurt.  In this manner it appears to be possible to eventually kill any hero, if at least a small amount of damage can be done to them.  But its not totally clear how this mechanic functions.  Does half of any damage become permanent, more or less?

I assume damage taken while under a hit point buff will not be permanent until the buff is totally consumed.

What percentage of data becomes permanent?

Is it different for different heroes or does it work the same way for all heroes and for all types of damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Each hero has a different "base regeneration" amount

***Some* heroes can enhance this base amount using Star Cards**

(for example, Bossk can "Name Your Poison" to regain full health from a Dioxis cloud )

---

**Luckily, you don't have to memorize these amounts.**

You can see what you'll regenerate in the game.

The health bar starts as a row of white blocks, each one representing 100 health points. The blocks start to turn grey when you take damage, and once you've taken more than you can regenerate, those grey blocks start to turn black. Only the grey blocks of health can be regenerated.

---

**Here are the base regeneration amounts for each hero:**

Light Side:

```
Luke:         200
Leia:         200
Han:          150
Chewbacca:    150
Lando:        150
Rey:          250
Yoda:         250
Finn:         250
```

Dark Side:

```
Boba Fett:    150
Bossk:        600
Darth Vader:  250
Palpatine:    300
Kylo Ren:     250
Darth Maul:   250
Iden:         150
Phasma:       150
```

Comment: I just regenerate almost the entire health of bossc from like 190 to 600.

Comment: @MarkRogers you're right, my research was incomplete. I've updated it, apparently Bossk has 600 base regeneration, and can use Dioxis clouds to do even better